# Starting VLC from command line always puts the window behind other windows

Tags: window-manager, vlc

If I start VLC from Finder, the windows shows up on top. But if I start VLC from the command line using `vlc` command (using either Terminal or iTerm2), the VLC window is never shows up on top. I have to use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to it. This is very annoying. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Btw, I don't want to make VLC always on top of other windows. But it should get focused (on top) when it starts.

Comment: Are you using the command `vlc` just to launch the player or are also passing command line arguments to it?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks a lot for the reply. Well, if `vlc file.mp4` is considering an argument, then both. Either way, VLC will not start on top. To clarify, `vlc` and `vlc file.mp4` both will put VLC window on bottom. They have the same behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to use command-line to:

- open a media file with VLC player

or

- simply launch VLC player

simply execute the following in the terminal emulator of your choice, respectively for above cases:

- `open file.mp4 -a VLC`
- `open -a VLC`

where `file.mp4` is the media file that you wish to open.

This will always cause the VLC media player window to show on top.

Comment: yeah, that works.. vlc has its own command line. I thought I won't need to create a shell script for this purpose, but I was wrong. I will write a script then. Thanks a lot again.